# split single column to several columns of binary matrix

Tags: r, binary

I have a big dataset in R which several individuals listed in several rows in one column for one area.

```
      ID Elevation Year Individual.code
1  Area1      11.0 2009              AA
2  Area1      11.0 2009              AB
3  Area3      79.5 2009              AA
4  Area3      79.5 2009              AC
5  Area3      79.5 2009              AD
6  Area5      57.5 2010              AE
7  Area5      57.5 2010              AB
8  Area7     975.0 2011              AA
9  Area7     975.0 2011              AB
```

I want to create a matrix by splitting the “individual code” into binary matrix without losing rest of the variables  i.e. ID, Elevation and Year

```
#     ID Elevation Year AA AB AC AD AE
#1 Area1      11.0 2009  1  1  0  0  0
#2 Area3      79.5 2009  1  0  1  1  0
#3 Area5      57.5 2010  0  1  0  0  1
#4 Area7     975.0 2011  1  1  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text = "      ID Elevation Year Individual.code
                 1  Area1      11.0 2009              AA
                 2  Area1      11.0 2009              AB
                 3  Area3      79.5 2009              AA
                 4  Area3      79.5 2009              AC
                 5  Area3      79.5 2009              AD
                 6  Area5      57.5 2010              AE
                 7  Area5      57.5 2010              AB
                 8  Area7     975.0 2011              AA
                 9  Area7     975.0 2011              AB", header = TRUE)

library(reshape2)
dcast(DF, ID + Elevation + Year ~ Individual.code, 
      fun.aggregate = function(x) as.integer(length(x) > 0))
#     ID Elevation Year AA AB AC AD AE
#1 Area1      11.0 2009  1  1  0  0  0
#2 Area3      79.5 2009  1  0  1  1  0
#3 Area5      57.5 2010  0  1  0  0  1
#4 Area7     975.0 2011  1  1  0  0  0
```

Comment: Hi @Roland , I am trying this code and getting the error message saying : unexpected ')' in "fun.aggregate = function(x) as.integer(length(x) > 0))"

Comment: I'd suspect that you are trying to run just that line. However, it belongs to the line before that and has to be run together with (or directly after) it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "      ID Elevation Year Individual.code
1  Area1      11.0 2009              AA
2  Area1      11.0 2009              AB
3  Area3      79.5 2009              AA
4  Area3      79.5 2009              AC
5  Area3      79.5 2009              AD
6  Areas      57.5 2010              AE
7  Area5      57.5 2010              AB
8  Area7     975.0 2011              AA
9  Area7     975.0 2011              AB", header = TRUE)

if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman"); library(pacman)
p_load(qdapTools, dplyr)

mtabulate(split(dat[["Individual.code"]], dat[["ID"]])) %>%
    matrix2df("ID") %>%
    left_join(distinct(select(dat, -Individual.code)), .)  

##      ID Elevation Year AA AB AC AD AE
## 1 Area1      11.0 2009  1  1  0  0  0
## 2 Area3      79.5 2009  1  0  1  1  0
## 3 Area5      57.5 2010  0  1  0  0  1
## 4 Area7     975.0 2011  1  1  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
spread(dat, Individual.code, Individual.code) %>% 
                  mutate_each(funs((!is.na(.))+0L), AA:AE)   
#     ID Elevation Year AA AB AC AD AE
#1 Area1      11.0 2009  1  1  0  0  0
#2 Area3      79.5 2009  1  0  1  1  0
#3 Area5      57.5 2010  0  1  0  0  1
#4 Area7     975.0 2011  1  1  0  0  0
```

Or you can use `reshape` from `base R`

```
 res <- reshape(cbind(dat, Col=1), idvar=c('ID', 'Elevation', 'Year'), 
           timevar='Individual.code', direction='wide')
 res[is.na(res)] <- 0
```